# React.DOM が undefined でエラーになる

Tags: javascript, reactjs

基礎的なことを学びたいので、まずはJSX無しで動かしたいと思い、`React.DOM.div` を使用すると以下のエラーが出ます。

```
build.js:20123 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'div' of undefined
```

---

コード

```
const React = require('react');
// 略

const HelloWorld = createReactClass({
  render: function() {
    return React.DOM.div({},
      'Hello World ' +
      this.props.name);
  }
});
// 略
```

---

package.json 一部、つまり、下記モジュールを npm install をしている。

```
"dependencies": {
  "create-react-class": "^15.6.3",
  "react": "^16.3.0",
  "react-dom": "^16.3.0"
}
```

HTMLのscriptタグの直接指定のCDNでReact単独とReact+JSXで動かすことはできています。
自分の書いたテクニックページです。

[React.js HelloWorldで理解するJSXの書き方(初歩的) - Qiita](https://qiita.com/standard-software/items/86f7e95d25a7285c1ff1)

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

`React.DOM` はReact 15.xで廃止が予告され、[16.0で実際に廃止されました](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#packaging)。

同じAPIを使い続けたい場合は、パッケージ [`react-dom-factories`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dom-factories) が利用できます。
現在、[公式ドキュメントで紹介されている](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html)のは、[`React.createElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement) を使う方法です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。大変参考になりました。
動作確認して、Qiitaにまとめ記事をいくつか書きました。助かりました。

React16 CDN でHelloWorld JSXありなし両方 - Qiita
https://qiita.com/standard-software/items/0cdbcdb2a6d6355c946b